# Vue template with v-if condition does not react on value change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, templates

I have a template with v-if condition base on the data value. But if I change the value it does not redrav the template. I see the value ich changed in Vue debugger but v-if blocks it like it was empty like on component load.

Here is the code:

```
<div v-if="newSelectedDevices" class="mt-2 mb-2">
    <template>
        <b-field class="has-horizontal-line pb-2">
            <b-taglist>
                <b-tag  v-for="(included, index) in newSelectedDevices"
                        :key="'included_' + index"
                          // This is the problem. It set is-hidden although isNew value is true
                        :class="{'is-hidden': included.isNew, 'taglist': true, 'is-danger': true}"
                        closable
                        @close="removeFromNewSelected(index)"
                >
                    {{ included.name }}
                </b-tag>
            </b-taglist>
        </b-field>
    </template>
</div>
```

[image]

What is wrong with this code? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you declare newSelectedDevices ?
Are you sure it is a reactive value ?

Comment: Depending of the type of `newSelectedDevices`, it may be `falsy`. Are you sure the type is `truthy` JS-wise?

Comment: I am sorry the problem is in :class condition for is-hidden class. Render takes it as false although I see the value is true. I add the screenshot of the value.